# Lifecycle of a script or a plugin in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lifecycle

I'm almost new to web developing and I'm facing to Javascript/jQuery. I would like to understand how a script is executed in an html page. I'm a C/Java programmer and references to these languages could help me.
I understood that a script can be inserted in the header or at the end of the body if we want to execute it after the page is loaded. I know that a function can be called by a DOM event (I associate events to interrupt signals). What I would like to know is if a script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var i=10;
if (i<5)
  {
  // some code
  }
//]]>
</script>
```

in the body or in the head element is executed only once or is executed continuously. Does jQuery behave in the same way as Javascript? 
What about plugins? Do they live for all the time a page is shown (like a parallel thread) or are they event driven (they are called by clicking/resizing etc or using timers)?
I know that is a very general question and that probably it cannot be explained in a few lines but some basic explanation and a link to some documentation would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is just a library written in JavaScript that mainly simplifies DOM manipulation and working with AJAX requests. If you want to understand how JS works, forget about jQuery for a moment.

Regarding script execution: The browser parses the HTML and creates a DOM out of it. When the browser encounters a `<script>` tag and its content, it creates a DOM element for it, adds it to the tree and executes the code. Then it continues parsing the next tag, which implies that the code is only executed once.
The reason for executing the script during parsing is that the script can already manipulate the HTML right away (using, e.g. `document.write` (not good practice though)) and therefore change what the parser has to parse. Script execution can be deferred using the [`defer` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-defer), until the document is fully parsed (I haven't seen the attribute very often in live code until now though).

All `script` tags share the same scope, the global scope and the execution environment persists until you navigate away or reload the page. So, defining a variable in one script and accessing it in the other is perfectly valid and in fact is what you are doing when you include libraries like jQuery in your page.

```
<script>
    var foo = 'bar';
</script>
<!-- other HTML code -->
<script>
    alert(foo);
</script>
```

---

You might find the [HTML documentation about `script`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) helpful.

Comment: The script can modify the DOM without using `document.write`

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yes, but that does not influence the parser. You can only modify what was already parsed. That's why I said "HTML" and not "DOM".

Comment: All the answers where useful but your clarify more the problem since you spoke also about the scope.
Another question, if I'll write something like this (in the proper way):
    <script>
      while(true)
      {
       i++;
       pause(100ms);
      }
    </script>
the execution will be blocked on this js or the page will be load in parallel when the processor if free?

Comment: @Alain1405: A feature like this does not exist in JavaScript. You could simulate this using timeouts, i.e. functions called after a certain amount of time. In that case the execution is not blocked and the page would continue to render.

Answer (score 3):

The script will execute top-to-bottom, once, just like anything else you load in the page. However, part of that loading will be to interact with the DOM (Document Object Model, or the browser's internal representation of the webpage), including registering event handlers etc.; thereafter events like clicks, AJAX responses, etc. can trigger JS functions.

If you're used to Java UI development, then callbacks and event-based programming will be familiar to you; if you're used to procedural coding then it'll be a bit of a learning curve.

Answer (score 2):

The code above will only execute once.

jQuery is javascript based and yes, of course, behaves the same way as javascript. jQuery makes javascript easier, and also deals with browser specific issues.

Javascript code is executed at runtime if it is written like in your example, but it may also be event driven. The lifecycle of the results of your code remain until you refresh your browser page. The lifecycle of a javascript may also be continuous if you are using timers.

Answer (score 1):

Some scripts just create functions and objects that can be called by events later, some scripts actually do something to the DOM as the page loads, some scripts just register listeners.

jQuery and their plugins just create object/functions that can later be called by event handlers.